# Annotation.equals() vs. Object.equals()

Tags: java, annotations, equals, guice, hashcode

Some frameworks (e.g. [guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#binding-annotations-with-attributes)) require in certain situations to create an **implementing class of an annotation interface**.

There seems to be a **difference** between the [`Annotation.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and  [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) definitions which need to be respected in that case (same applies for [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#hashCode())).

**Questions:**

- Why was it designed that way and what is the reason of the difference?
- What side-effects can occur when using the `Object.equals(Object)` definition for annotation classes instead?

***Update:***

Additional questions:

- What about the [`Annotation.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#hashCode()) definition? Is it really required to implement it that way, especially the "*(...)127 times the hash code of the member-name as computed by String.hashCode()) XOR the hash code(...)*"-part?
- What happens if a `hashCode()` method is implemented to be consistent to `equals()` but doesn't match the exact definition of `Annotation.hashCode()` (e.g. using 128 times the hash code of the member-name)?

Comment: Actually the question about `hashCode` is the only interesting part, on first look it seems overspecified. Also it's unusual that it uses a linear combination of all member hashcodes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: As a very rough guess: it's specified in that detail because the runtime environment also creates an implementing class for each annotation and it should be guaranteed that all implementing classes uses the same hashCode() definition in order to not cause any issues with hash-based collections (but I could not find a proof for this yet).

Comment: Yes, one way to understand it is that annotations are interfaces and `hashCode` is implementation. Yet each implementation of the same annotation interface should behave exactly the same way, just as if the annotation type itself was a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions are not different. The definition in `Annotation` is simply *specialized* for the annotation type.

The definition in `Object` basically says "If you decide to implement  `equals` for your class, it should represent an equivalence relation that follows these rules".

In `Annotation` it defines an equivalence that follows those rules, which is meaningful specifically for `Annotation` instances.

In fact, the `Annotation` equivalence would work for many other classes. The point is that different classes have different meanings, and therefore their instances may have different equivalence relationships, and it's up to the programmer to decide which equivalence relation to use for his/her class. In `Annotation`, the contract is for this particular equivalence relation.

As for side effects - suppose an `Annotation` type inherited `Object`'s equals. This is a mistake many people do when they try to use their own classes in maps or other `equals()`-dependent situations. `Object` has an `equals()` function that is the same as object identity: two references are equal only if they are references to the same object.

If you used that, then no two instances would be considered the same. You would not be able to create a second Annotation instance that would be equivalent to a previous one, despite them having the same values in their fields and semantically representing the same sort of behavior. So you wouldn't be able to tell if two items are annotated with the same annotation, when they have different *instances* of the same annotation.

---

As for the `hashCode` question, although Jeff Bowman has already answered that, I'll address that to make my answer more complete:

Basically, implementation of annotations is left to compilers, and the JLS doesn't dictate the exact implementation. It is also possible to create implementing classes, as your question itself mentions.

This means that annotation classes can come from different sources - different compilers (you are supposed to be able to run `.class` files anywhere, no matter which java compiler created them) and developer-created implementations.

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are usually considered in a single class context, not in an interface context. This is because interfaces are usually antithetic to implementation - they only define contracts. When you create these methods for a particular class, you know that the object you compare with is supposed to be of the same class, and thus have the same implementation. Once it has a `hashCode` method that returns the same value for objects that are equivalent under `equals` for the same class, then whatever that implementation is, it satisfies the contract.

However, in this particular case, you have an interface, and you are required to make equals() and hashcode() to work not only for two instances of the same class, but for instances of different classes that implement of the same interface. This means that if you don't agree on a single implementation across all possible classes, you might get two instances of the same annotation with the same element values, and different hash codes. This would break the `hashcode()` contract.

As an example, imagine an annotation `@SomeAnnotation` that doesn't take parameters. Imagine that you implement it with a class `SomeAnnotationImpl` that returns `15` as the hash code. Two equal instances of `SomeAnnotationImpl` will have the same hash code, which is good. But the Java compiler would return `0` as the hash code when you check the returned instance of its own implementation of `@SomeAnnotation`. Therefore two objects of type `Annotation` are equal (they implement the same annotation interface and if they follow the `equals()` definition above, they should return `true` for `equals`), but have different hash codes. That breaks the contract.

Comment: Ok, I understand that Annotation.equals() narrows the Object.equals() definition, but does not violate it - but what about Annotation.hashCode()? (I've updated the question)

Answer (score 2):

RealSkeptic's answer is great, but I'll put it a slightly different way.

This is a specific instance of a general problem:

1. You defined an interface (specifically an annotation).
2. Someone (javac) wrote a particular (built-in) implementation of that interface. You can't access that implementation, but need to be able to create equal instances, particularly for use in Sets and Maps. (Guice is one big `Map<Key, Provider>` after all.)
3. The implementor (javac) wrote a custom implementation of equals so that annotation instances with the same parameters pass `equals`. You need to match that implementation so that `equals` is symmetric (`a.equals(b)` if and only if `b.equals(a)`, which is assumed in Java along with reflexivity, consistency, and transitivity).
4. Equal objects must have equal `hashCode`s because Java uses it as a shortcut for equality: if objects have unequal hashCodes then they cannot be equal. This comes in handy to make the efficient Map implementation HashMap, because you can use the `hashCode` to only check objects in the right `hashCode`-determined bucket. If you used a different or modified `hashCode` algorithm, you'd be breaking spec in theory, and in practice your annotation implementation wouldn't match others consistently in HashSet or HashMap (rendering it worthless to Guice). Many other features use hashCode, but those are the most obvious examples.
5. It would be much easier if Java let you instantiate their implementation, or generate an implementation automatically for your class, but here the best they've done is an exact spec for you to match.

So yes, you'll run into this with annotations more often than anything else, but these matter any time you're trying to act equal with an implementation you can't control or use yourself.

Comment: +1 In summary, the issue is with disparate classes having to agree on implementation detail, which is not normally required. It stems from the mismatch of annotations as interfaces and reified annotations as instances.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are excellent general answers to the question, but since I haven't seen them mentioned I'll just add that the use of AnnotationLiteral for implementing Annotations takes care of the equals and hashCode issues properly.  There are a couple to choose from:

[AnnotationLiteral](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html%20AnnotationLiteral)
[AnnotationLiteral](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b27/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/AnnotationLiteral.html)